# CI load library function using CI instatnce

Tags: codeigniter

```
<?php
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->library('MenuList','menu');
print_r($CI->menu->selectMenu('admin'));
?>
```

I have the above code in my php page. I want to load the function `selectMenu()` from the Menulist page in the Libraries.

I have below in my Menulist page:

[image]

But i get nothing from `$CI->menu->selectMenu('admin')`

How to correctly load the data from this kind of loading?

UPDATE:

I have this in my autoload:

[image]

UPDATE:

I used model as follows:

```
<?php
$CI =& get_instance();
// $CI->load->library('MenuList','menu');
$CI->load->model('folder/MenuList','menu');

$menu = $CI->menu->selectMenu($UserProfile);
?>
```

I can get result.

> Why didnt it work with load library and worked with load model?

Comment: this is you adding new library

Comment: It looks to me like you are attempting to use CI classes outside of the context of the framework. (Did that make sense?) Is that the case?

Comment: The CI function `get_instance()` won't return anything until a "Controller" has been instantiated within the context of the CI framework. Your first snippet of code seems like it might be procedural code, but CI is an OOP based framework.

Comment: @DFriend you are correct I want to create a class with just an array of menu. And load those array as menu in my project

Answer (score 0):

if you are using new library that assign in autoload.php file:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('MenuList');
```

And where you using this library:

```
$CI->load->library('MenuList');
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work:

```
$CI->load->library('MenuList');
$menu = $CI->menulist->selectMenu($UserProfile);
```

So something is wrong in the loading. Look in `system\Loader.php`:

```
/**
 * Library Loader
 *
 * Loads and instantiates libraries.
 * Designed to be called from application controllers.
 *
 * @param   string  $library    Library name
 * @param   array   $params     Optional parameters to pass to the library class constructor
 * @param   string  $object_name    An optional object name to assign to
 * @return  object
 */
public function library($library, $params = NULL, $object_name = NULL){}
```

You use `menu` as the second argument - this is an error.

Here's the fix:

```
$CI->load->library('MenuList', [], 'menu');
$menu = $CI->menu->selectMenu($UserProfile);
```